Computing Rice CDF values in spreadsheets
Is it possible to compute CDF values for the Rice distribution using standard spreadsheet functions?
The following probability distribution functions are available in spreadsheets:

Normal
t
F
Chi-square
Gamma
Exponential
Weibull
Poisson

Since some of these are closely related to the Rice distribution, I was thinking there could be some clever tricks to get Rice CDF values from them.

It is possible, but not very efficient.  If $X \sim \operatorname{Rice}(\nu,\sigma)$ then $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = 1 - Q_1\left(\frac{\nu}{\sigma}, \frac{x}{\sigma}\right), \tag{1}$$
where $Q_n(a,b)$ is the Marcum Q-function.  Using the second formula recommended for numerical computation
$$Q_N(\sqrt{2NX}, \sqrt{2Y}) = \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} e^{-Y} \frac{Y^m}{m!} + \sum_{m=N}^\infty e^{-Y} \frac{Y^m}{m!} \left(1 - \sum_{k=0}^{m-N} e^{-NX} \frac{(NX)^k}{k!} \right), \tag{2}$$
substituting the required variable values, and observing that the term in parentheses in $(2)$ is actually just the CDF of a suitable gamma distribution,
we have
$$F_X(x) = 1-e^{-(x/\sigma)^2/2} \left(1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{((x/\sigma)^2/2)^m}{m!} F_G(\nu^2/2) \right), \tag{3}$$
where $G \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(m, \sigma^2)$ is gamma with shape $m$ and scale $\sigma^2$ with density
$$f_G(g) = \frac{g^{m-1} e^{-g/\sigma^2}}{\sigma^{2m} \Gamma(m)}. \tag{4}$$
Consequently, an implementation in a spreadsheet program that supports efficient computation of the gamma CDF would allow calculation of a suitably truncated version of $(3)$.  In particular, we might use a table approach and calculate for each $m$ the summand in $(3)$, incrementing $m$ until the value decreases below some precision threshold.  Then we would add the terms and multiply by $e^{-(x/\sigma)^2/2}$.
In Excel, the gamma distribution CDF specified in $(3)$ is given by
GAMMA.DIST(nu^2/2, m, sigma^2, TRUE)

hence the summand is
((x/sigma)^2/2)^m/GAMMA(m+1) * GAMMA.DIST(nu^2/2, m, sigma^2, TRUE)

where you would need to relate the value of $m$ to a corresponding row or column of consecutive positive integers.

Thank you -- this is a very clever and helpful answer!
